# Set Hook in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, native

I can't set a state with Hooks in React Native. After call setMyvariable, I get an [object Object].
I can see that with a simple alert...
Please... Help me... Why append this...?
This is the code:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const PageArticle = () => {
  const [FindRollNo, setFindRollNo] = useState("12");
  const [RollNo, setRollNo] = useState(undefined);
  const [StudentName, setStudentName] = useState(undefined);
  const [Course, setCourse] = useState(undefined);

  const SearchRecord = () => {
    var FindRollNo = {FindRollNo};
    alert(FindRollNo);
    
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }, styles.viewStyle}>
      <TextInput
          placeholder={'Enter RollNo'}
          placeholderTextColor={'#ff0000'}
          keyboardType={'numeric'}
          style={styles.txtStyle}
          onChangeText={(value) => setFindRollNo(value)}
      />
      <Button title={'Find Record'} onPress={SearchRecord} />
      <TextInput
          style={styles.txtStyle}
          value={RollNo}
      />
      <TextInput style={styles.txtStyle} value={StudentName} />
      <TextInput style={styles.txtStyle} value={Course} />
      {/*<Text>Article Screen ciao </Text>*/}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: You get `[object Object]` when you force an object into a string. And you should use lowercase for your state variables.  Also, what's `var FindRollNo = {FindRollNo};` supposed to do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You've wrapped `FindRollNo` in curly braces, which turns the value into an object.

Fortunately, you can access `FindRollNo` directly. Here's an Expo Snack showing how:

https://snack.expo.dev/@coolsoftwaretyler/trembling-blueberries

The code looks like this. Pay attention mostly to the difference in `SearchRecord`, which just alerts `FindRollNo` directly without creating a new variable or anything.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const PageArticle = () => {
  const [FindRollNo, setFindRollNo] = useState("12");
  const [RollNo, setRollNo] = useState(undefined);
  const [StudentName, setStudentName] = useState(undefined);
  const [Course, setCourse] = useState(undefined);

  const SearchRecord = () => {
    alert(FindRollNo);
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <TextInput
          placeholder={'Enter RollNo'}
          placeholderTextColor={'#ff0000'}
          keyboardType={'numeric'}
          onChangeText={(value) => setFindRollNo(value)}
      />
      <Button title={'Find Record'} onPress={SearchRecord} />
      <TextInput
          value={RollNo}
      />
      <TextInput  value={StudentName} />
      <TextInput value={Course} />
      {/*<Text>Article Screen ciao </Text>*/}
    </View>
  );
};

export default PageArticle
```

Comment: You're right !!! Thanks! But in my guide was wrotten that I must use curly braces... It's very strange... However, thank you very much!!!